# Why would Beautifulsoup be returning NoneTypes when fed a mechanize response?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm attempting to log into twitter to do some scraping of recent tweets. I have the following code:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import html5lib


twitter = 'https://mobile.twitter.com/session/new'
br = mechanize.Browser()
response1 = br.open(twitter)

br.select_form(nr=0)
br['username'] = 'MYUSERNAME'
br['password'] = 'MYPASSWORD'

br.submit()

req = br.click_link(text='Me[IMG]')
response = br.open(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
soup.prettify() #does nothing at all
soup.head #also does nothing at all
```

I've been using Mechanize + Beautiful soup for the past few days on *multiple* sites and haven't run into this issue. Heck, even on some of twitter's other pages the above code works fine. I try printing `prettify()`, but it doesn't work. It gives me the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb7' in
>   position 6972: ordinal not in range(128)

I do some google-fu, and I find that this is relating to the encoding, so I adjust my code to be:

```
soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8')
```

And this works for the most part. I mean, it at least prints everything. But none of that data seems to be "in" the instance of soup as it normally is. For instance, I can't access `soup.head`, not `soup.body`. `Soup.find('foo')` does nothing, as well as plain old, `soup.b`. If I print the type of `soup.head` it return `NoneType`, so I am all kinds of confused!

What's going on here?

Edit: Wha..? Why is this being downvoted?  : (

Comment: Is there data when you `response.read()` before passing it to soup?

Comment: @tijko Yeah. I can call `print response.read()` and all of the html is there, which makes Beautifulsoup not reading it quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a bug in Beautiful Soup's html5lib tree builder](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1039527). I've committed a fix which will be in the next release. In the meantime, I recommend you tell Beautiful Soup to [parse the markup using lxml instead of html5lib](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).